# Parallel Solving with PDPTW in OptaPlanner

Tags: parallel-processing, optaplanner, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to increase OptaPlanner performance using parallel methods, but I'm not sure of the best strategy.

I have PDPTW:

- vehicle routing
- time-windowed (1 hr windows)
- pickup and delivery

When a new customer wants to add a delivery, I'm trying to figure out a fast way (less than a second) to show them what time slots are available in a day (8am, 9am, 10am, etc). Each time slot has different score outcomes. Some are very efficient and some aren't bookable depending on the time/situation with increased drive times.

For performance, I don't want to try each of the hour times in sequence as it's too slow.

How can I try the customer's delivery across all the time slots in parallel? It would make sense to run the solver first before adding the customer's potential delivery window and then share that solved original state with all the different added delivery's time slots being solved independently.

Is there an intuitive way to do this? Eg:

1. Reuse some of the original solving computation (the state before adding the new delivery). Maybe this can even be cached ahead of time?
2. Perhaps run all the time slot solving instances on separate servers (or at least multiple threads).

What is the recommended setup for something like this? It would be great to return an HTTP response within a second. This is for roughly 100-200 deliveries and 10-20 trucks.

Thanks!

Comment: About pdptw: taxi problems (= non mixed pick up and delivery) are straightforward in OptaPlanner. Dial a ride problems (= mixed pick up and delivery) are difficult (need custom moves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) If you optimize the assignment of **1 customer to 1 index in 1 of the vehicles**, while *pinning* all other already assigned customers, then you forgoing all optimization benefits. It's not NP-hard.
You can still use OptaPlanner `<constructionHeuristic/>` for this (`<localSearch/>` won't improve the score), with or without moveThreadCount to spread it across cores, even though the main benefit will just the the incremental score calculation, not the AI algoritms.

B) Optimize assignment of **all customers to an index of a vehicle**. The real business benefits - like 25% less driving time - come when adding a new customer allows moving existing customer assignments too. The problem is that those existing customers already received a time window they blocked out in their agenda. But that doesn't need to be a problem if those time windows are wide enough: those are just hard constraints. **Wider time windows = more driving time optimization opportunities (= more $$$, less CO² emissions).**

---

**What about the response within one minute?**

At that point, you don't need to *publish* (= share info with the customer) which vehicle will come at which time in which order. You only need to *publish* whether or not you accept the time window. There's two ways to accomplish this:

C) Decision table based (a *relaxation*): no more than 5 customers per vehicle per day.

Pitfall: if it gets 5 customers in the 5 corners of the country/state, then it might still be infeasible. Factor in the average eucledean distance between any 2 customer location pairs to influence the decision.

D) By running optaplanner until termination feasible=true, starting from a warm start of the previous schedule. If no such feasible solution is found within 1000ms, reject the time window proposal.

Pitfall with D): if 2 requests come in at the same time, and you run them in parallel, so neither takes into account the other one, they could be feasible individually but infeasible together.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, the business case is actually junk removal, so there are several pickups before having to unload at a transfer station. It's pretty challenging because there's the capacity problem mixed in, but also, depending on the type of junk a customer has, this can determine the unload location for that junk.

That makes sense regarding the time windows (bigger windows, better optimization potential).

So you suggest custom moves (which are best?), but also most gains are to be had from construction heuristics and not local search when adding incremental customers?

Comment: I'd avoid custom moves, if I can. Just pickup junk until the capacity is full and then go to the nearest unload location. A shadow variable can decide after every junk pickup whether it's time to go unload before driving to the next one.

Comment: Thanks - over booking with too many customers is a primary challenge I'm trying to solve (customers get angry when late, etc). Yeah I was hoping to not need a custom move, but the score improvements currently don't plateau until close to a minute, so I will really need to optimize somehow.

Comment: I am afraid custom moves are to escape plateau's, not to reach them faster. Score calculation speed (see info logging) above 10 000 help to reach the plateau sooner.